# In MVC, Workflow Service not working wihout any error

Tags: model-view-controller, workflow-foundation

I am calling WF as a service (hosted as a Service Reference in client)from my MVC web client. After publish when I deploy and hosting WebClient and WF service in my local machine IIS it is working and workflow calls all the defined activity. But when I am deploying same build on Production Server (Windows Server 2012) then seems WF service not getting called without any error. Please find below code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewFeed(FeedProcessViewmodel fpmodel)
{
    //some database object creation and saving

    waiting to save the data into database and use the generated request id
    sBL.SaveFeedDetailAsync(m_objMasterSnapShot, m_objMasterFeed, m_objFeedDetail);

    //calling windows workflow service
    InputRequest objInputRequest = new InputRequest { RequestId = "requestid" };
    ServiceClient objServiceClient = new ServiceClient();
    OutputResponse outputResponse = objServiceClient.SubmitRequest(objInputRequest);

    if (!outputResponse.Success)
    {
        oDic.Add("Error", outputResponse.Message);
        jrResult.Data = oDic;
        throw new Exception(outputResponse.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        //CALLING THIS LINE AFTER OUTRESPONSE LINE EXECUTION
        // BUT ALL THE ACTIVITY WITHING WORKFLOW NOT EXECUTED
        oDic.Add("Ok", outputResponse.Message);
        jrResult.Data = oDic;
    }
}
```

Any help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its too late to reply to this post as I actually forgot to add an update for this.

The reason for above issue was at InputRequest class constructor.

```
InputRequest objInputRequest = new InputRequest { RequestId = "requestid" };
```

Had code which was returning null and because InputRequest class had try-catch block, actual error was suppressed and not propagated to calling place.